# Carry Rails session across domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, multiple-domains

I'm looking for a solution to carrying sessions from one domain to another using Rails. You can read the full details in a gist I made: [Session hijack myself](https://gist.github.com/gimpporbust/0224c2c939620375741c).

The gist has a "solution", but I'm really looking for something better and more reliable.

Thanks guys!